# how to add bundle products through metafields in shopify

Tags: shopify

i wanted to add bundle products through metafields in my shopify store on product page, such that the selected products are added to cart through single add to cart button

this is the applied code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Enable "Add to Cart" button when a product is selected
    $('.selector').on('change', function() {
      if ($('.selector:checked').length > 0) {
        $('#add-to-cart-button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('#add-to-cart-button').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });

    // Submit selected products to cart using Shopify AJAX API
    $('#add-to-cart-button').on('click', function() {
      var selectedProducts = [];
      $('.selector:checked').each(function() {
        selectedProducts.push($(this).val());
      });
      if (selectedProducts.length > 0) {
        Shopify.cart.addVariants(selectedProducts, { quantity: 1 }, function(items, cart) {
          alert('Selected products have been added to your cart!');
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```